# React Native - Expected argument type 'RCTViewManagerUIBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, reactjs, react-native

we want to use the [react-native-sprite](https://github.com/williamngan/react-native-sprite) to animate some png sequences in our app. Unfortunately we got the following error when we want to build the app:

**Cannot convert value of type '(RCTUIManager!, [NSNumber : UIView]!) -> ()' to expected argument type 'RCTViewManagerUIBlock!'**

The following code is throwing the error:

```
// Let's start with some spaghetti to get a view!
self.bridge!.uiManager.addUIBlock { (uiManager: RCTUIManager!, viewRegistry:[NSNumber : UIView]!) in
  let view: Sprite = viewRegistry[reactTag] as! Sprite;

  // The first parameter is not named, but the second one requires a name. Whatever!
  view.createSequence( nameWithPath, count:count, format:format, duration:duration );
}
```

I'm not that familiar with react-native objective-c lib.

Answer (score 0):

[A fix](https://github.com/williamngan/react-native-sprite/commit/79a1378e631ee0216077d6d64ffd8248e4c73556) is now in the repo. Hope this works for you.

Side-note: This component is quite experimental with rough edges. Please test it throughout if you're using it in production. Large image sequence may be slow to load or crash the app in older phones, for instance.